# Chromium automatically installed in xubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: xubuntu, chromium

After latest packages update, I noticed that Chromium is installed in Xubuntu 22.04LTS.
Certainly I never installed Chromium before, neither with Software app nor with sudo apt.
I'm the only person who uses this computer, and I have strong password.

I suspect of VirtualBox package, that maybe installed Chromium at same time, but I don't know really.

Should I be worried?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You should be able to see why it was installed in `/var/log/apt/history.log*`, if this happened (indirectly) through `apt`. Otherwise `/var/log/dpkg.log*` should give the low level log.

Comment: I fact it was installed with an update, but I can't understand why. I copy some logged messages here. Sorry, I don´t know how to format text.Start-Date: 2023-03-07  18:33:48
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.88'
Upgrade: libreoffice-l10n-en-gb:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, .......... libreoffice-style-elementary:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.2), chromium-browser-l10n:amd64 (1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2, 1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2.22.04.1)
End-Date: 2023-03-07  18:35:12

Comment: I'm confused here... but I'd not be worried.. I see it in https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/jammy/release/xubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.manifest  which actually surprises me!   alas not in the [seed](https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/xubuntu.jammy/desktop), I'm exploring this..  I've booted a QA-test install of jammy.2 RC & yep `chromium-browser` *deb* package IS INSTALLED, but not the *snap* package ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd not be worried..

I see `chromium-browser` in https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/jammy/release/xubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.manifest though that surprised me

`chromium-browser   1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2`

It's not in the [seed](https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/xubuntu.jammy/desktop) as that only mentions `firefox`

but `chromium-browser` also found on manifests of

- 2022-04-19 `chromium-browser        1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2`
- 2022-08-09 `chromium-browser        1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2`
  so it's not new.

I booted a few QA-test installs of *jammy.2* I did rather recently (before release of [Ubuntu 22.04.2](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/02/24/ubuntu-22-04-2-lts-released/) and noted the *deb* package of `chromium-browser` installed.  I can't recall (*and aren't going to look up testcases for the installs; one install [here](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/442/builds/272151/testcases/1301/results)*) but I suspect those installs were offline, but no `chromium` *snap* package was installed (*that would require internet to download given its not on the ISO unlike `firefox` snap*)

---

Later update:

I've been told by [Krytarik](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekrytarik) the following patch

[https://git.launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/ubuntu-seeds/+git/xubuntu/commit/?id=ed3698ba0b35919bc3326444c96752a7bda8a9db](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Exubuntu-dev/ubuntu-seeds/+git/xubuntu/commit/?id=ed3698ba0b35919bc3326444c96752a7bda8a9db)

"*I guess this should have been backported to 22.04*" to prevent this.

Relevant bug is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xubuntu-meta/+bug/1991470

Comment: @arraybolt3 noted "*I see that libreoffice-help-* has a Suggests on chromium-browser*"  but no 'smoking-gun' has been found (yet)

Comment: Probably obvious.. but once you see the patch the reason is obvious..   the *surprise* I initially expressed replaced by '*doh!  of course the depends rule will pull something in given prior `firefox` is now a snap & thus not seen*'   adding that empty firefox *deb* resolves the *depends* rule minimally...